# PySimpleGUI for scripts with optional arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse, pysimplegui

I have a script which utilizes optional arguments with the help of `argparse`. When the optional arguments are not in use they default to `None`. I'm trying to build a GUI for the script with `PySimpleGUI`. The types for these optional arguments are:

- `Directories`
- `Text files`
- `Integers`

I looked, but I could not find anything in the [documentation](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) with regard to having fields for optional arguments. What needs to be specified for optional directories, files, and integers?

The code to call on files is:

```
[sg.Text('Choose an optional text file:', size=(100, 1)), sg.Input(), sg.FileBrowse()]
```

The code to call on directories is:

```
[sg.Text('Choose an optional directory:', size=(100, 1)), sg.Input(), sg.FolderBrowse()]
```

The code to get an integer is:

```
[sg.Text('Enter optional number to the right:', size=(100,1)),sg.Spin(values=[i for i in range(1, 100000)], initial_value=1, size=(6, 1))]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is something like...

```py
if args.dir is None:
   # ask for dir
if args.files is None:
   # ask for files
if args.inter is None:
   # ask for integer
```